# c# custom AssemblyResourceLoader

Tags: c#, url-routing

I am routing all request myself, which get me into the problem of WebResource.axd requests, the solution I thought of is to modify the dot net framework code of AssemblyResourceLoader class, as CustomAssemblyResourceLoader, and set it to handle WebResource.axd requests. I am using Lutz Roeders Dot Net reflector to access the framework code.

The first step is to compile the code, I am implementing CustomAssemblyResourceLoader as follows (please note that whole AssemblyResourceLoader is copy-paste in CustomAssemblyResourceLoader just for now):

```
namespace System.Web.Handlers
{
    public sealed class CustomAssemblyResourceLoader : IHttpHandler
    {
        ...
        private static VirtualPath _smartNavPageLocation;
        ...
```

I have added all the required references and namespaces, but I am still getting compilation error:

> 'System.Web.VirtualPath' is
>   inaccessible due to its protection
>   level

If VirtualPath is inaccessible to CustomAssemblyResourceLoader, then how is it accessible to AssemblyResourceLoader. What would be solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because VirtualPath is marked *internal*.  Only code inside System.Web.dll can use it.  That has to be bad news, there's no decent workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hans for your response, it helped me a lot to make design decision.

... It is time for decorator pattern ...

Silly M_Soft beat it ;)